# CentOS 6.0 Server hostname changes at reboot

Tags: linux, centos, hostname

Every time I boot, CentOS 6.0 Server hostname disappears. I have to re-issue hostname command to reset it.

Please help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you need to set your host name properly in /etc/sysconfig/network

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=localhost
DOMAIN=localdomain
GATEWAY=yourgatewayaddress
```

Comment: Works! Wonder how the network file got updated automatically?! I remember putting the correct fqdn while installation!!!
Thanx a lot!

Comment: not a problem glad to help.

For some reason it does this on some of my servers too on a fresh install, dont have the time to look into why.. i just make it practice to check this after the install completes before i do the rest of the server configuration, a 2 second check :)  Could be something to do with SELinux, but wouldnt like to say for sure :)

Comment: @JDI Can I do this via some kind of one-liner?

Answer (score 4):

Add a line

```
HOSTNAME=your.hostname.tld
```

to the `/etc/sysconfig/network` file to set the hostname to `your.hostname.tld`

Comment: I think you typically do not want the FQDN here, instead you want the short hostname.  The domain should be present in `/etc/resolv.conf` and, optionally, in a `DOMAIN=` variable in the same file.

Comment: @KyleSmith: No, you would normally put the fqdn here for both [CentOS 6](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/rhel6/rhel_6_deployment/rhel_6_deployment_ch-The_sysconfig_Directory.html#s2-sysconfig-network) and [CentOS 5](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s2-sysconfig-network.html). No mention of a DOMAIN setting in either document either.

Comment: Works! I put the whole fqdn in the network file. Will try what you are suggesting too! For now, issue resolved. I'm new to Linux and these small things frustrate a lot :-P Thanx!!!!

Comment: @Iain, can you point me to the documentation you're looking at.  Maybe I'm doing it wrong :)

Comment: @KyleSmith: I did, the links are CentOS 6 and Centos 5 above

Comment: @Iain I can tell you as certified RHEL 6 admin, that the fqdn does NOT belong in /etc/sysconfig/network, but should only appear in /etc/resolv.conf if you are not using NetworkManager, which you should not if this is a server. Try the `hostname -d` comand. If it gives you the right domain you did it right. At least that's what I learned in my courses, and seems logical.

Comment: Correction, the domain goes in resolv.conf, not the fqdn

Comment: @YanickGirouard: can you explain the documentation I link to above then in particular the CentOS 6  link which points to the RHEL 6 documentation ?

Comment: @YanickGirouard, I just verified that the links provided by Iain are clones of the official RedHat docs.  This seems to be incorrect as the HOSTNAME variable is assigned to the hostname parameter inside the kernel, which (my understanding is) should **not** be the FQDN.

Comment: One isn't just a clone it's the official RHEL 6 Documentation

Comment: @Iain: Ok, here's the deal. The RHEL doc is not wrong, but it's not right either. It all depends on your /etc/nsswitch.conf hosts line, your /etc/resolv.conf and your /etc/hosts file. If the kernel is not able to match the hostname to either a DNS record or a record present in /etc/hosts, nothing will work right. So you can put both, but you need to either have the proper domain defined in resolv.conf (either domain or search will work) or have both the shortname and fqdn as the first entry after the IP in /etc/hosts (fqdn first).

Comment: @Iain: If you use the /etc/hosts method however, the `hostname` command will always give you the FQDN as the result. If this is what you want, good. Otherwise, you'd have to rely on your DNS and /etc/resolv.conf